# Does index affect on performance of where is not null query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, where-clause, sql-server-2016

I'm looking for perform my query:

```
SELECT TOP(100) [Id] FROM [Order] 
WHERE [HasInvoice] = 0 AND [City] IS NOT NULL
```

And here is my schema:

```
[Order]:

    [Id]           NVARCHAR(10)  NOT NULL,
    [FirstName]    NVARCHAR(40)  NOT NULL,
    [LastName]     NVARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
    [City]         VARCHAR(10)   NULL,

    .....
 
    [HasInvoice]   BIT           NOT NULL
```

I was thinking to have an index on ([Id], [HasInvoice])

but I'm not sure if I have an  index on ([Id], [HasInvoice], [City]) will be better or not?

Any idea please?

Comment: For understanding indexes, Brent Ozar has an an excellent free video series called [How to think like an SQL Server Engine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fERXOywBhlA) that I found really improved my understanding of how indexes are used - which in turn helps to choose the columns, and column orders, for indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of those indexes will help.  The index you want is `(HasInvoice, City, Id)` or `(City, HasInvoice, Id)`.

Making `id` the first column in the index prevents the `where` clause from taking advantage of the remaining columns.

Comment: Oh, the order does matter. Thank you

Comment: Order does matter, yes. Note that the answer isn't completely thorough. An index can be used in two ways. First is to reduce reads (e.g., instead of reading from the whole table, read just from the index) but still needs to read all rows. Your index `(Id, HasInvoice, City)` is like this - and arguably Gordon's second `(City, HasInvoice, ID)`. The second way indexes are used is to allow index seeks. The other index `(HasInvoice, City, Id)` is like this - it can go straight to the first point where HasInvoice = 0 and City is not null, then read until HasInvoice becomes 1. This is very efficient.